# Is there a way to prevent creation of a data class item in C# WindowsForms UserControl

Tags: user-controls, windows-forms-designer

If I create a UserControl, to create and edit an instance of a data class e.g. Person in C# WindowsForms (call it PersonControl), the framework automatically adds an instance of Person in PersonControl.Designer with some default values for the properties and fills the item controls with those values. This behavior has a number of side effects which I would like to avoid.

Question: is there a defined way to prevent creation of a data class instance in UserControl.Designer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you missing the [DesignerSerializationVisibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute?view=net-6.0) attribute. If you have a custom control every public property that you add will automatically be serialized. You can use this attribute to disable the serialization for a property. I also recommend to add the [Browsable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute?view=net-6.0) attribute which will hide the property from the designer. If you want more control over serialization, like you want to serialize only when another property is set to true you can create a special named method which will then called by the designer [Defining Default Values with the ShouldSerialize and Reset Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/defining-default-values-with-the-shouldserialize-and-reset-methods?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). There was a MSDN Magazine where a lots of winform learning resource was relased there are some gems about winform internal working. If you interested in you can quickly look trhrough it. My favorite is. [Create And Host Custom Designers With The .NET Framework 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/march/create-and-host-custom-designers-with-the-net-framework-2-0)

Comment: Thanks Krisztián. To be more concrete: suppose I want a user control to create and edit a most PersonData (Name, DateOfBirth. Gender). It should get and set the fields of the PersonData  class via GUI, that is, via 

public PersonData PersonData
{
  get{//...}
  set{//...}
}

Where do you mean I should set the DesignerSerializationVisibility attribute? 
[DesignerSerializationVisibility]
class PersonData {...} 
?
I have not yet been able to test thoroughly.

Comment: Hi @StanislavKoncebovski. You're close but controls have many properties if you put the attribute on the class how do you know which property is affected by it? I posted another answer with the code. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74324204/8495803)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but i didn't mention another attribute [DefaultValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?view=net-6.0) You can use the attribute the following way.

```
public partial class PersonEditControl : UserControl
{

    [DefaultValue(null)] // This attribute tells the designer if the property value matches what we specified in the attribute(null) it should not store the property value.
    public PersonData? Person { get; set; }

    public PersonEditControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we really need the question mark after PersonData here? It is nullable by itself, isn't it?